# Nuxt.js, problem with fetching data in async fetch() hook

Tags: api, axios, nuxt.js, lumen, econnrefused

I'm having some trouble fetching data from my API in both the async fetch() hook and async data(). I get the error: "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED". If I try to fetch the data in the mounted() hook instead, it works normally. I've built the API in Lumen and when I've tried with a different API(which I've also built in Lumen and is running online) it also worked normally. I'd assume the problem is in the API, but I don't understand how is it working in mounted() then. I've tried using both axios and $http and I get the same result.

UPDATE
I've tried putting in "fetchOnServer: false" and it works like that, so it looks like the problem is with fetching data on the server side.

Comment: I have some components that only work in a deployed page when I use `"fetchOnServer: false"` on them. Others, if I add `"fetchOnServer: false"` it breaks my Jenkins build, but nothing in the logs says what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If someone sees this and has the same problem, the solution for me was to start the lumen application with:
`php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public`
instead of `php -S http://localhost:8000 -t public`